# Convert .rtf to .txt

Tags: r, text-mining

I've bunch of .rtf files (in hundreds). I need to convert them into text format for text mining. I think the best way to go about it by first converting rtf to pdf and then pdf to text (That way no data loss occurs). 
Is there any other possible way to do it? 
Does package 'tm' in R has some way to create corpus of .rtf files?